EF Core 8 specification pattern variable referenced from scope ', but it is not defined
When invoke the expression, i become an InvalidOperationException

variable '___zip_0' of type 'System.Int32' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

SpecificationBase class
     public abstract class Specification<TEntity> where TEntity : class
        {
            public abstract Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> ToExpression();
        
            public bool IsSatisfiedBy(TEntity entity)
            {
                Func<TEntity, bool> predicate = ToExpression().Compile();
                return predicate(entity);
            }
           
            public Specification()
            {
                
            }
            public Specification( Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>>? criteria) 
                => Criteria = criteria;
            public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Criteria { get; set; }
        
            public List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> IncludeExpression { get; } = new();
            public List<Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>>> NestedIncludes { get; }
                    = new List<Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>>>();
            public List<string> IncludeStrings { get; } = new List<string>();
            public Expression<Func<TEntity,object>>? OrderByExpression { get; private set; }
            public Expression<Func<TEntity,object>>? OrderByDescendingExpression { get; private set; }
        
            protected void AddInclude(Expression<Func<TEntity,object>> includeExpression)=> IncludeExpression.Add(includeExpression);
            protected virtual void AddNestedInclude(Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> nestedIncludeExpression)
            {
                NestedIncludes.Add(nestedIncludeExpression);
            }
            protected virtual void AddInclude(string includeString)
            {
                IncludeStrings.Add(includeString);
            }
            protected void AddOrderBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderByExpression)
                => OrderByExpression = orderByExpression;
        
            protected void AddOrderByDescending(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderByDescendingExpression)
               => OrderByDescendingExpression = orderByDescendingExpression;
        
            public Specification<TEntity> And(Specification<TEntity> specification)
            {
                return new AndSpecification<TEntity>(this, specification);
            }
           
            public Specification<TEntity> Or(Specification<TEntity> specification)
            {
                return new OrSpecification<TEntity>(this, specification);
            }
           
        }
    

Specification in use
          
   public class AddressByZipSpecification : Specification<Address>
        {
                public int _zip { get; set; }
                public AddressByZipSpecification(int zip)
                {
                    _zip = zip;
                }
                public override Expression<Func<Address, bool>> ToExpression()
                {
                    return address => address.Zip == _zip;
                }
        }

How i use the specification in the test
 var zipSpec = new AddressByZipSpecification(12);
  var address = await dbContext.Address.Where(a =>  zipSpec.ToExpression().Invoke(a)).ToListAsync();

I am at a loss, what happend in the expression tree

What is ToExpression() where does that come from?

The ToExpression() comes from the base class, it is as abstract declared. I added base class above.

You can't Invoke an Expression inside another EF Core Expression and expect it to work.
Your easiest option is to cache the Expression and pass it in directly
var zipExpr = zipSpec.ToExpression();
var address = await dbContext.Address.Where(zipExpr).ToListAsync();

If you need to combine this expression with other expressionn then you may want to look at LinqKit, which can transform expression calls within other expressions.

Thx it works. In the Include where clause i received the esc again. What happends here ?  var zipExp = new AddressByZipSpecification(12).ToExpression();  var result = await dbContext.Person.Include(p => p.AddressList.Where(a => zipExp.Invoke(a))).ToListAsync();

You can't invoke it inside another expression, you'd need LinqKit for that (or try do it yourself with some really complex Expression rewriting)
